# ASP.net Webservice Missing Xheader confirmation email is blank

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have asp.net webservice package built by previous developer now has stopped working. It still posts the request to remote server but in return it is supposed to send confirmation back to our server which it fails.

I check the script header and it appropriately assigned the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings code block to (ConfirmationEmail) parameter available in app.config file.

But on receiving end we don't see the confirmation email.

Can you help me whats going on here.

[image]

[image]

On the receiving end, we are not seeing email address that we passed through X-Vendor-Email

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the custom header be added to headers instead of part of the content type?

ie.

```
oWeb.Headers.Add("X-Vendor-Email", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConfirmationEmail"));
```

Comment: Yes we did that oWeb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8;")
oWeb.Headers.Add("X-Vendor-Email=", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConfirmationEmail")+";")      That is not working either.

Comment: I just noticed the comment.  i see there's an = at the end of X-Vendor-Email, that shouldnt be there. also the request object should take care of the semicolon at the end.  should just have the key and value.

Comment: Thank You i will try that and get back to you